# Spring jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am new to Spring MVC and JDBCTemplate and badly need some help on this. I've declared the following in applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pwd" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

In my DAOImpl class, I've the following code:

```
@Repository
public class ABCDAOImpl implements ABCDAO
{

    private String INSERT_SQL = null;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate( dataSource );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insertDataInDataBase(final Object obj)
    {
        boolean insertSuccessful = false;

        INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO XXX " +
                "(AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, " +
                "FF, GG, HH, II) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() 
            {public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) 
                           throws SQLException
                {
                  PreparedStatement ps = null;
                  ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);
                  ps.setString(1, xx);
                  ps.setString(2, xx);
                  ps.setString(3, xx);
                      ps.setString(4, xx);
                  ps.setString(5, xx);
                  ps.setString(6, xx;
                  ps.setString(7, xx);
                  ps.setString(8, xx);
                  ps.setString(9, xx);
                  return ps;
                  }}, keyHolder);

        return insertSuccessful;    
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
  import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
    public class ABCDAOImplTest
    {
    private Object object = new Object();
    private ABCDAOImpl abcDAOImpl;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        object.setAllVaribles();
        abcDAOImpl = new ABCDAOImpl();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRepositoryInsert()
    {
        System.out.println(abcDAOImpl.insertDataInDataBase(object));
        assertTrue(abcDAOImpl.insertDataInDataBase(object));
    }

}
```

Then I use jdbcTemplate to carry out an insert statement using PreparedStatementCreator.
Now, I am trying to test (without mocking, I am hardcoding the values just to test..) whether this code works or not? When I run this test, it gives me NPE saying jdbcTemplate is null. Is there something wrong with my code or is there something with the way I am testing it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Happy New Year :)

PS - I have annotated the Test class with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"}) only after comment from @Pradeep. And now I get another exception: "Failed to load ApplicationContext."

Comment: Is your `DAOImpl` class covered in your `component-scan`?

Comment: Yes, it is.    <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.def.xxx.packageName" />

Comment: 1. try  <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.def.xxx.*" />

2. try to inject based on instance variable jdbcTemplate not on the setter

Comment: Use @Repository on the DAOImpl.java

Comment: @swamy I have done that.

Comment: @Gavrav.....my Strong guess would be the issue lies in the test class `setup` method.You are creating a new Object for `ABCDAOImpl`. But when you start the server spring container already instantiate a obejct for `ABCDAO`. So just put `@Autowired ABCDAOImpl` instead creating with new keyword and try.

Comment: Can you share the entire `applicationContext.xml` file? Do you have a component scan path in configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious answer is that your test hasn't called the `setDataSource()` method or done anything else that would cause the JdbcTemplate to be created. You haven't shown enough code for someone to point out where the problem is, though.

**Update:** In your test, you say `abcDAOImpl = new ABCDAOImpl();`, and that's all. How do you expect the JdbcTemplate/DataSource to be injected? It won't happen by magic. Either you have to finish wiring it all up manually, or else let Spring inject the DAO into your test. To do that, just add a field like this:

```
@Autowired
private ABCDAO abcDao;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code is pretty unreadable. Format it properly with an IDE, then paste it into your question, select it all, and click the "code" button in the editor to make it useful.

Comment: It sounds like your original problem was that you weren't even starting Spring for your test, but you were expecting it to be autowiring things for you. Now you're trying to start it but have some other problem with your configuration.

Comment: yes you are right. I have tried to use the "code" button. Please let me know if I could something else.

Comment: Yes, that's much better. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Ryan and everyone else for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your missing Import of `applicationContext.xml` file in `test-applicationContext.xml` file

```
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext.xml" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've progressed further with your help. I haven't created a separate test-applicationContext.xml, just annotated my test class with the applicationContext (I've put the entire code in the post). I have annotated my class with @RunWith(SpringJunit4Runner.class) and @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"}). Now, when I run the JUnit test, it says "Failed to load Application Context."

Comment: Test class not able to find applicationContext file.